# Differential equation $xy'+2y=0$ and the form of arbitrary constant in its general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

If I'm solving the differential equation in the title I will get to:
$$\log(y)=-2\log(x)+c$$
then I'll get
$y=e^c/x^2$ eith arbitrary constant $c$.

So I know I can write $y=d/x^2$ where $d$ is an arbitrary positive constant. But now it's easy to see that $d$ can be negative or zero as well. How can I see that from the derivation? Can I reason from the derivation that $d$ can be arbitrary? (I know I can just show $d$ can be arbitrary e.g. by calculating $y'$ and see that $d$ cancels out.)

Comment: Cases where $d\le 0$ correspond to infinite or complex cases of $c$.

Comment: OK, makes sense. can you explain the infinite case? Where d=0

Comment: Hint: Write the equation as $x^{-2}\frac{d}{dx}(x^2 y) = 0$ for which it follows directly that $x^2y = c$ where $c$ can be any number positive or negative (and is fixed by a initial condition $y(x_0) = y_0 \to c=y_0x_0^2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're more careful, you can see that $d$ can be arbitrary.

First of all, to solve $xy' + 2y = 0$ as you have done, you need to rewrite it as $$\frac{y'}{y} = -\frac{2}{x},$$ but that assumes $y$ is non-zero. Treating the $y = 0$ case separately, you see that $y \equiv 0$ is a solution which can be rewritten as $$y = \frac{d}{x^2}$$ where $d = 0$.

As for the $d$ negative case, note that $\log x$ is not an antiderivative for $\dfrac{1}{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ because the former isn't even defined for $x < 0$. The correct statement is that $\log|x|$ is an antiderivative for $\dfrac{1}{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Therefore, by antidifferentiating both sides of the equation

$$\frac{y'}{y} = -\frac{2}{x},$$

we obtain

$$\log|y| = -2\log|x| + c.$$

Now if you rearrange for $y$, the presence of absolute values will produce a $\pm$ which allows for negative $d$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I didnt really get the last part "Now if you rearrange for y, the presence of absolute values will produce a ± which allows for negative d."

Comment: What I mean is that if you start with $\log|y| = -2\log|x|+c$ and try to find $y$, you will at some point have an expression for $|y|$; have you been able to do this?

Comment: ah man, i really need 2 sleep. thanks for the answer

Comment: I was referring to the fact that $d = \pm e^c$ so $d$ can be positive or negative.

Comment: I know. I just need to find some sleep.. But have to wait till tonight... Thanks for the help